# dtstart warning on UserComments schema

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

I have the following code for rich snippet on comments:

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments">
    <li id="comment-1" class="comment">
        <span itemprop="name" class="author">Author 1</span>
        <p itemprop="commentText">Bla Bla Bla</p>
        <time itemprop="commentTime" content="2012-07-29" datetime="2012-07-29T05:55+00:00" title="Jul 29, 2012 5:55">2 days ago</time>
    </li>

    <li id="comment-2" class="comment">
        <span itemprop="name" class="author">Author 2</span>
        <p itemprop="commentText">yada yada yada</p>
        <time itemprop="commentTime" content="2012-07-30" datetime="2012-07-30T04:44+00:00" title="Jul 30, 2012 4:44">yesterday</time>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

According to [schema.org/UserComments](http://schema.org/UserComments), this is correct. However, [Google's Rich Snippets Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) is giving an warning:

> Warning: Missing required field "dtstart".

`dtstart` is not even a property of UserComments event. Should I ignore this warning (Google's tool is beta)? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I found the answer. The correct HTML code seems to be like this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="comment-1" itemtype="http://schema.org/Comment" itemscope="itemscope" itemprop="comment">
        <span itemprop="author">Author 1</span>
        <p itemprop="text">Bla Bla Bla</p>
        <time itemprop="dateCreated" content="2012-07-29" datetime="2012-07-29T05:55+00:00" title="Jul 29, 2012 5:55">2 days ago</time>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Each comment has its own itemscope. It means you have to repeat `itemtype="http://schema.org/Comment" itemscope="itemscope" itemprop="comment"` on each comment.

I came to this conclusion after checking [Google's example for "Products with many offers"](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http://www.ebay.com/ctg/Samsung-Galaxy-Nexus-SCH-I515-32GB-Black-Verizon-Smartphone-/110853084). They use as example a eBay page that contains multiple reviews about the product. [Review](http://schema.org/Review) and [Comment](http://schema.org/Comment) are both part of [CreativeWork](http://schema.org/CreativeWork).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the Google validator to correctly validate a page using `UserComments`. I admit it's hard to decide which is the preferred comment format to use (`UserComments` vs `Comment`), but http://schema.org/CreativeWork declares `comment` to be of type `UserComments`, so I'm going with that for now.

Assuming your instance of `UserComments` is inside something like a `CreativeWork`, I believe the key to avoiding this validation error from Google is adding the `itemprop='comment'` property to `UserComment` `itemscope` element.

In your case, try to update your  line to include that attribute, i.e.:

```
<ul itemprop="comment" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments">
```

I found that when `UserComments` contained in a `CreativeWork` contain the correct `itemprop`, Google parsed them correctly with no error. I did see this error when `itemprop='comment'` was missing, I believe Google is treating it as a generic event in that case. Incidentally, `startDate` is a synonym for `dtstart` (ref: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/164506?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

Use it without: itemprop="comment"

```
<ul>
    <li id="comment-1" itemtype="http://schema.org/Comment" itemscope="itemscope">
        <span itemprop="author">Author 1</span>
        <p itemprop="text">Bla Bla Bla</p>
        <time itemprop="dateCreated" content="2012-07-29" datetime="2012-07-29T05:55+00:00" title="Jul 29, 2012 5:55">2 days ago</time>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tries and errors I have found something that works and passes tests I did with a testing tool.

```
<div itemprop="comment" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments">
    <p itemprop="commentText"> bla bla bla </p>
    <span itemprop="name" class="author">billy bob</span>
    <span itemprop="commentTime" content="2014.2.28" >Feb 28 2014</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This (at least currently) also produces the error in Google’s tool: Missing required field "dtstart".