# UserComments in test: “dtstart required”, but not part of standard?

Tags: html, microdata, google-search-console, schema.org

I put some effort in marking up an ancient message board with [schema.org/UserComments](http://schema.org/UserComments) microdata. Testing it in [WMT](http://www.google.de/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) yields an error message: `Missing required field "dtstart"`.

Here’s an item, and apart from the `table` markup, I think it’s all fine:

```
<tr itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments" itemprop="comment">
    <td>
        <meta content="2013-09-23T17:39:14+01:00" itemprop="commentTime">
        <meta content="http://example.com/cmts/?id=321" itemprop="replyToUrl">
        <meta content="comment’s title" itemprop="name">
        <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemprop="creator">
            <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/user/Nickname">
            <img itemprop="image" src="http://cdn.example.com/pic.jpg">
            <span itemprop="name">Nickname</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p itemprop="commentText">the comment’s actual text</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In [UserComments](http://schema.org/UserComments), there’s no field named “dtstart”. In a [similiar, yet not helpful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740569/), there’s another [link to WMT](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/164506?hl=en), stating somewhat implicit that `startDate` and `dtstart` are synonyms. This does not prove true, at least not for `UserComments`.

Is it a hitch at Google, so I can disregard it? Am I missing some point (`datetime` instead of `content`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Microdata and Schema.org usage is correct. They don’t define any required properties. So when the *Google Structured Data Testing Tool* reports "Missing required …" errors, it only means that Google (probably) won’t consider displaying a Rich Snippet when specific properties are missing.

When testing your snippet with a parent item for the `comment` property, no errors are reported, e.g.:

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
  <table>
  <!-- your tr here -->
  </table>
</article>
```

Another solution: adding a [`startDate` property](http://schema.org/startDate) (but Google might want to see a date from the future here.)

(The term "dtstart" probably comes from the data-vocabulary.org vocabulary, where [Google required this property for the *Event* Rich Snippet](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/164506?hl=en). And Schema.org’s UserComments is also some kind of Event, see notes below.)

If you don’t care about Google’s Rich Snippets, you can keep it like that.

---

Notes about your snippet:

- You might want to use [Comment](http://schema.org/Comment) instead of [UserComments](http://schema.org/UserComments) (because the latter one is an Event, not a CreativeWork).
  However, currently, the [`comment` property](http://schema.org/comment) expects UserComments, but this will most likely change in one of the next Schema.org updates.
- For specifying `replyToUrl`, you [must](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728910/1591669) use `link` instead of `meta`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was concise in detail. Google’s cognition of microdata is actually something I do care about. Regarding the usage of `Comment`, I’ll wait and see, since schema.org/Comment is not that descriptive right now. As for `link` elements, I thought they “may only appear in the HEAD section of a document”. Anyway, the superordinate `CreativeWork` solved the actual problem.

Comment: dtstart actually comes from vcalendar http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/dtstart.html